# send parameters from Fragment to Activit

Tags: android

I have one Activity and 4 fragment, in the bottom i MainActivity.xml I have 4 buttons static for that I call fragment A, B, C, D. when I press Home button I call Fragment A and button change image green, when a press button search I call fragment B and button change image green, while button Home change image white.
if I want to turn back from fragment B to A with BACK BUTTON, how can a tell MainActivity to change image i green Home Button.

I need to send one parameters from Fragment to Activit.[image]

Comment: You are simulating a `ViewPager` here. But a catch of `onBackPressed()` in your `Activity` should catch it all and make the fragment change as well as your ViewPager-ish update.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Fragment->Activity communication for that.
Just @Override onBackPressed in the Activity, and if the current fragment is NOT Fragment A, move to Fragment A. Otherwise call super.onBackPressed..

For generic communication between the 2, have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).